# Saving UIImage as binary to SQLite and retrieving it with imageWithData

Tags: ios, sqlite, uiimage, nsdata

I am saving some images to a SQLite database in my app. I accessed the database with a graphical SQLite client and it is saving the binary of my images correctly. The problem is on retrieving it from the database.
This is whats it looks like:

Save

```
-(void)insertObject:(Object *)object
{
    const char* sqliteQuery = "INSERT INTO OBJECTS (OBJECTID, OBJECTIMAGE, OBJECTNAME) VALUES (?,?,?)";

sqlite3_stmt* statement;

if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, sqliteQuery, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )

{

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [object.id UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 2, [object.imgData bytes], [object.imgData length], SQLITE_STATIC);

    sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [object.name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_step(statement);

}

else NSLog( @"SaveBody: Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(databaseHandle) );

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Retrieve

```
-(Object *)retrieveObjectWithID:(NSString*)id
{

NSString* sqliteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT OBJECTIMAGE,OBJECTNAME FROM OBJECTS WHERE OBJECTID = '%@'", id];    
NSLog(@"sqlitequery: %@",sqliteQuery);
sqlite3_stmt* statement;

Object *object = [[Object alloc]init];

object.id = id;

if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseHandle, [sqliteQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )

{

    if( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )

    {

        NSUInteger length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1);

        object.imgData  = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1) length:length];
        object.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

    }

}


// Finalize and close database.

sqlite3_finalize(statement);


return object;
}
```

this is the Object

```
@interface Object : NSObject


@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *id;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSData *imgData;

@end
```

Comment: what is the issue you having with the data retrieve ?

Comment: it retrieves me a tiny hexadecimal, that doesnt let me build an uiimage from

Comment: What is the type of "OBJECTIMAGE" field on database table ? is it varchar ?

Comment: This is the statement that creates the table:   `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STORES (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,STOREID TEXT, STOREIMG BLOB, STORENAME TEXT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following code,

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 0)];

object.imgData = data;
```

instead of,

```
NSUInteger length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1);

        object.imgData  = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1) length:length];
```

Comment: It gives me the same thing. Instead of a huge hexadecimal from the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` it returns me this `<50524f44 55544f53>`

Comment: @LucasPereira: I have found the issue, you are assigning the image name to image data. I have updated the above code. Yur data is in the OBJECTIMAGE row, so you ned to use 0 instead of 1 in sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 0)